# MongoDB C# Using custom extensions in Linq or Lambda Query, for checking string similarity

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I'm trying to get from Mongo collection only that "x.SystemName" is similar at 80% to input string. It works when i load all entries from collection to variable, but i want to get results directly from database.

This code works:

```
IEnumerable<Company> companies = await FindAllCompanies();
IEnumerable<Company> _dbresult = (from company in companies
                                           where company.SystemName.StringRateSimilarity(inputSystemName) >= 0.8 || company.SystemName.Contains(inputSystemName) || company.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(name.ToLowerInvariant())
                                           select company);
```

But i want to make it like this without previously loading all Companies to variable:

```
IEnumerable<Company> _dbresult = (from company in _db.DatabaseHost.GetCollection<Company>(collectionName).AsQueryable()
                                           where company.SystemName.StringRateSimilarity(inputSystemName) >= 0.8 || company.SystemName.Contains(inputSystemName) || company.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(name.ToLowerInvariant())
                                           select company);
```

or like this:

```
var collection = _db.DatabaseHost.GetCollection<Company>(collectionName);
IEnumerable<Company> _dbresult = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => (Services.API.StringRateSimilarity(x.SystemName, inputSystemName) >= 0.8) || (x.SystemName.Contains(inputSystemName)) || (x.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(name.ToLowerInvariant()))).Select(e => e);
```

But this make *InvalidOperationException: StringRateSimilarity({document}{systemName}, "TEST") is not supported.* Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the MongoDB C# driver to be able to translate a C# Expression into a MongoDB query it needs to "know" how to do that. With your handwritten method, there is no way the driver could know what your method does and hence how MongoDB could do the same thing on the Database side (which may or may not be possible).

I would suggest you tackle that problem from the other side:

1. Try to express your "80% similarity" logic using a pure MongoDB query.
2. Translate that MongoDB query into C# using only the built-in string functions that are supported by the C# driver or alternatively resort to sending that raw MongoDB query as a string.